# How to blur/dim an activity when a popup window is shown in android

Tags: android, popupwindow

I use a popupwindow for displaying options in Android. I tried to dim/blur the activity when a popupwindow is active, but I did not find a solution... can anybody help me.

I used the following code but it does not work for me.

```
getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  
lp.dimAmount=0.0f;  
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);  
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

Comment: Thanks LAS_VEGAS for giving response. but i used the above code but it is not working with popup window in android.

Comment: I am also looking for a way to blur the background when a popup window is displayed.  Anyone come up with this solution yet?