# Putting the main screen in the background whilst loading?

Tags: android

I'm using a `AsynTask` and when I go into the processing, which is fetching some info off a webserver I want to display a loading dialogue. Currently I have a Progress spinner which I make visible on `onPreExecute` but I wanted to put the rest of the UI out of focus whilst it does this.

What is the correct way to do this, should I be using a pop-up type of dialogue instead of just a progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...but I wanted to put the rest of the UI out of focus whilst it does this.
```

I have a good idea here why don't blur the window of your app to have the effect you need

```
      WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  
      lp.dimAmount = 0.0f;  
      dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);  
      dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND)
```

[How to blur/dim an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8386471/488434)

---

or by using [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) example of using `ProgressDialog`:

```
      ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MyApp.this);
      pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
      pd.setMessage("Working...");
      pd.setIndeterminate(true);
      pd.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: +1 for ProgressDialog. Unfortunately, `FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND` [doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372404/alternative-to-flag-blur-behind-in-android) for some versions.

Comment: Ha, I didn't realize until after I commented that I was out of votes for the day. Will fix when I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can sue [dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) there yu can make your custom one with spinner and text and set it `MY_DIALOG.setCancelable(false)` until it finish loading the data.